# D3.js svg path data is not updating in the screen when the user minimises the browser or when open new tab

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using this example to build my chart. The chart doesn't update when the user minimises the browser or when open new tab.

This behaviour can be observed in the below link also.

https://jsfiddle.net/kvjawptr/4/

```
  if (lineToDraw === ".line1") {
    clipRect1.attr("width", increment);
    clipRect2.attr("width", newWidth);
    clipRect2.attr("transform", "translate(" + increment + ", 0)");
  } else {
    clipRect2.attr("width", increment);
    clipRect1.attr("width", newWidth);
    clipRect1.attr("transform", "translate(" + increment + ", 0)");
  }
```

How can i continuously update the chart even when the DOM is not in view.

Comment: Try using a viewBox like `.attr("viewBox",`0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${height + margin.top + margin.bottom} `)` instead of `/*.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)*/`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome